# Query returning too many rows, seems to be duplicating

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a query to give me a specific set of information, however it doesn't seem to be quite right. I believe I'm missing a key thing here but I can't think of what it is. Here is my query as it is now.

```
select
    per.Forenames
    , per.Surname
    , p.Identifier2
    , ef.UlcerL
    , ef.UlcerR
    , ef.UlcerTypeL
    , ef.UlcerTypeR
    , pf.AmputationType
from
    Patient p
    join Episode e on e.PatientID = p.PatientID
    join Person per on per.PersonID = p.PersonID
    join EpisodeFoot ef on ef.EpisodeID = e.EpisodeID
    join PatientFootAmputation pf on pf.PatientID = p.PatientID
where
    ef.UlcerL = 1 or ef.UlcerR = 1
    and DATEDIFF(year, e.EpisodeDate, getdate()) > 2010
```

I am getting perhaps 10 rows per person with the exact same results and I have no idea why. 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Also, it seems as if the pf.AmputationType isn't giving me any results, which I don't think is true.

edit: This is what I am seeing right now. The row is just being duplicated.

```
|Forenames|Surname|Identifier2|UlcerL|UlcerR|UlcerTypeL |UlcerTypeR|AmuptationType|
|---------|-------|-----------|------|------|-----------|----------|--------------|
|   Joe   |Bloggs | 12345678  |  1   |  0   |Neuropathic| NULL     | Medial       |
|   Joe   |Bloggs | 12345678  |  1   |  0   |Neuropathic| NULL     | Medial       |


ORDINAL_POSITION    COLUMN_NAME              DATA_TYPE    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH  IS_NULLABLE
1                  PatientFootAmputationID  uniqueidentifier    NULL                 NO
2                  PatientID                uniqueidentifier    NULL                 YES
3                  AmputationDate           datetime            NULL                 YES
4                  AmputationWhichLeg       varchar             50                   YES
5                  AmputationNumber         varchar             50                   YES
6                  AmputationArea           varchar             300                  YES
7                  AmputationType           varchar             300                  YES
8                  AmputationDescription    varchar             -1                   YES
9                  AmputationSize           varchar             100                  YES
10                 AmputationCondition      varchar             200                  YES
11                 AmputationComments       varchar             -1                   YES
```

Comment: Show us the table definition and a sample data with expected result

Comment: Can you tell me what you mean by table definition? Sorry, I'm not terribly great at SQL.

Comment: your create table script

Comment: If you do `select *` you'll probably find the explanation.

Comment: I would also recommend parenthesis on your `OR` condition like `(ef.UlcerL = 1 or ef.UlcerR = 1)`

Comment: Okay. I have sorted out the duplicates. I didn't think it was going to be so simple, but all I needed to do was add a `distinct`. Now, the only thing I need to get working is the final column.

Answer (score 0):

If the other table you are joining with has multiple records with joined key then you are bound to get similar rows. You can consider using `ROW_NUMBER()` function like

```
select * from (
select
    per.Forenames
    , per.Surname
    , p.Identifier2
    , ef.UlcerL
    , ef.UlcerR
    , ef.UlcerTypeL
    , ef.UlcerTypeR
    , pf.AmputationType
    , row_number() over(PARTITION BY p.Identifier2) as rn
from
    Patient p
    join Episode e on e.PatientID = p.PatientID
    join Person per on per.PersonID = p.PersonID
    join EpisodeFoot ef on ef.EpisodeID = e.EpisodeID
    join PatientFootAmputation pf on pf.PatientID = p.PatientID
where
    1 in (ef.UlcerL , ef.UlcerR)
    and DATEDIFF(year, e.EpisodeDate, getdate()) > 2010 ) xxx
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: as much as this may work, I think the OP must first investigate the cause of the duplicates. Not taking anything from the correctness of the answer